# Чего опасаться со стороны пользователя?

Tags: php, безопасность

У пользователя есть свой личный кабинет с набором форм и текстовых полей.
Чего стоит опасаться? Есть хороший материал по этой теме?

Comment: ты это... пользователя не баись. Баись харкеров. Вот почитай http://hashcode.ru/questions/241399/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: главное данные из форм экранируй и всячески обрамляй функциями блокирующие не функциональный скрипт, чтобы не было непредвиденных ситуаций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL - инъекций](http://www.php.su/security/?databases2#same) в первую очередь - если безоглядно доверять всему что приходит от пользователя, то есть шанс что он сможет сделать что угодно с вашей бд.
Материал например вот: http://www.php.su/security/